# elastic search master not discovered in single node cluster elastic search v 7.11.1

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, centos

I am trying to set up three node elastic search in single vm. But master node is not at all discovering. If I start with cluster.initial_master_nodes as one node.
Master is elected but cluster formation is not happening and RemoteTransportException is occured. I tried too hard and multiple possibilites but no luck.

Here is my configuration.

I tried the same configuration with windows its working fine. But linux cent os I am facing the problem.

```
Os Version: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Elastic : 7.11.2 RPM Distribution
Node1

cluster.name: escluster
node.name: master-1
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["master-1", "master-2","master-3"]
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 3

Node2

cluster.name: escluster
node.name: master-2
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9201
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["master-1", "master-2","master-3"]
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 3

Node3
cluster.name: escluster
node.name: master-3
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9202
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["master-1", "master-2","master-3"]
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 3
```

All the three nodes are starting successfully. But the cluster formation is not happening.

```
[2021-04-10T15:04:22,868][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [master-1] publish_address {x.x.x.x:9301}, bound_addresses {[::]:9301}
[2021-04-10T15:04:23,246][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [master-1] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2021-04-10T15:04:23,435][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterBootstrapService] [master-1] bootstrapping cancelled
java.lang.IllegalStateException: requirement [master-1] matches multiple nodes: [{master-1}{yQiAG1tJS7uwgNiyJ3suWg}{k4haC3AdQXiSrceLevHHaA}
{x.x.x.x}{x.x.x.x:9301}{cdhilmrstw}{ml.machine_memory=8078663680, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.max_jvm_size=536870912},
 {master-1}{H4T0B4AdTiWVYHW9Dzi0qw}{tQlVqLzYT3OJXtaug6K3cQ}{x.x.x.x}{x.x.x.x:9300}{cdhilmrstw}{ml.machine_memory=8078663680, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, 
 ml.max_jvm_size=536870912, transform.node=true}]

 curl  -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "master_not_discovered_exception",
        "reason" : null
      }
    ],
    "type" : "master_not_discovered_exception",
    "reason" : null
  },
  "status" : 503
}
[2021-04-10T15:24:20,990][WARN ][o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper] [master-1] master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, 
and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [master-1, master-2, master-3] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{master-1}{RVGdv8o4R7mEZS8G3pF9IQ}
{Ue_VMHc_RFqOjLeW9aJiUw}{x.x.x.x}{x.x.x.x:9302}{cdhilmrstw}{ml.machine_memory=8078663680, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, 
ml.max_jvm_size=536870912}, {master-1}{H4T0B4AdTiWVYHW9Dzi0qw}{tQlVqLzYT3OJXtaug6K3cQ}{x.x.x.x}{x.x.x.x:9300}{cdhilmrstw}{ml.machine_memory=8078663680,
 ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_jvm_size=536870912, transform.node=true}, 
 {master-1}{yQiAG1tJS7uwgNiyJ3suWg}{k4haC3AdQXiSrceLevHHaA}{x.x.x.x}{x.x.x.x:9301}{cdhilmrstw}{ml.machine_memory=8078663680, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_jvm_size=536870912, transform.node=true}]; discovery will continue using [127.0.0.1:9300] from hosts providers and [{master-1}{RVGdv8o4R7mEZS8G3pF9IQ}{Ue_VMHc_RFqOjLeW9aJiUw}{x.x.x.x}{x.x.x.x:9302}{cdhilmrstw}{ml.machine_memory=8078663680, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20, ml.max_jvm_size=536870912}] 
from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Your configuration shows 3 nodes, are you running the 3 nodes in the same host? If this is right, you need to use different `path.data` for each one of your nodes. If you want a single node cluster you can't have other nodes in the `cluster.initial_master_nodes` config and you need to set `discovery.type: single-node` also. Can you explain better what you are trying to do? You say that you want a single node but your config has three nodes.

Comment: Thanks .Yes I am running the three nodes in same host. I tried changing the path as well but it's not working cluster formation not happening. I need to set up elasticsearch cluster and configure that in gravitee api gateway for high availability

Comment: @leandrojmp Sorry for the mistake in question I have updated my question. In single machine I am creating 3 nodes

Comment: The config seems right, but try to change the `discovery.seed_hosts` to the private ip of your machine to see if this works. Is there anything else in the logs for the other nodes? Anyway, running the 3 nodes in the same server you won't have high availability, if your server goes down your entire cluster will go down. It makes no difference running a single node or a 3 node cluster in the same server in this case.

Comment: I tried changing seeds hosts but it's not working.  If I changed data path also its using old data path not using newly created one

Answer (score 0):

change YMLs as below:

```
node1:
http.port: 9200
transport.port:9300
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["master-1"]
node2:
http.port: 9201
transport.port:9301
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1:9300"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["master-1:9300"]
node3:
http.port: 9202
transport.port:9302
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1:9300"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["master-1:9300"]
```

Comment: Thanks Hamid Bayat. I tried with the configuration you mentioned but I am facing failed to bind 127.0.0.1:9300 error while starting up node 2

Comment: before that check what is binding of 9200 and ip? netstat -anpl |grep 9200. is it 127.0.0.1?

Comment: configure 127.0.0.1 master-1 in /etc/hosts

Comment: 127.0.0.1:9200 . Port binding error is coming for 9300 port

Comment: Failed to find 0.0.0.0:9300

Comment: If I commented transport.port it's starting successfully. But each node having unique Custer ID not running as cluster

Comment: Failed to find 0.0.0.0:9300 . because the port is occupied. check what process use this port. master-1 must use port 9300. and master-1 must start first.

Comment: you need to bind ports static.

Comment: Master 1 running using 9300 but master 2 also trying to use that port eventhough I specified different transport in configuration

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67042135/elastic-search-is-not-using-data-path-setting

Comment: It's referring config 1 transport port I guess

Answer (score 0):

Before starting cluster we need to ensure the node is created. After node is created cluster is forming as expected.